# What is the most appropriate way of injecting daos in services, services in controllers in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

There are many annotations in the Spring framework like @Component, @Service, @Repository, @Service @Resource and @Autowired etc.

What is the most appropriate way of injecting my daos in services, and my service class in the Spring Controller.

With so many annotations it is getting confusing especially with @Autowired working for all situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Service` and `@Repository` are just "sub-annotations" for `@Component` to specify the bean a bit more (to separete Services from Repositories for more sophisticated stuff). From the point of injection this three are equal.

For injection, there are 3:

- `@Resource`
- `@Inject`
- `@Autowired`

`@Autowired` is the most powerful annotation, but `@Resource` (JSR-250) and `@Inject` (JSR-330) are standardized. — Anyway if you not plan to reuse your application in a non-Spring environment, then I would not pay to many attention to this concern.

Answer (score 2):

See **[Annotation based configuration in Spring](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/seemarich/archive/2007/11/annotation_base.html)**, best `Spring Annotation` tutorial for me.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to avoid annotations, especially if they start getting confusing.  Nothing wrong with good old getter and setters in this case.  Just gotta wire the bean on your own, which isn't so difficult that annotations are necessary.

Comment: I have been using this old approach for years with getters and setters and the xml files. But with new version of spring I would like to try the annotations.

Comment: The extra xml config is another layer of complexity (weather simple or not, it does count as another layer).  Java is a noisy language as it is, setters/constructors just for the sake of injection makes code look even more clunky.  I don't know of an IDE that refactors xml files when Java code needs to change.